# lock background reference image (Blender 2.8)

Tags: 3d-view

I am working in the Jeep Wrangler tutorial (new to blender) .

It is extremely difficult to have a dynamic workflow without pressing my reference images while I try to press a mesh. Is it possible to LOCK the reference images ?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Make the Empty not selectable

In the outliner, uncheck the "arrow" icon next to the name of your empty.

## Lock the transformations

In the Properties sidebar (<kbd>N</kbd>), check the "lock" icons next to the Location/Rotation/Scale properties.

Comment: on the visibility tab, uncheck the selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Man can I ask for help, the "arrow" button doesn't show up on me that's why I can't deselect it. Is there any hotkeys for locking the reference image?
[image]

Comment: Look in the top right of the Outliner tab (the tab containing Scene Collection etc, from your image) for a sub-menu called "Restriction Toggles"; it has a symbol that looks a little bit like a triangular key on it. In that sub-menu, you can choose which Restriction Toggles to make visible. By default in 2.80, only Visibility is present, but in this sub-menu you can turn on/off the Selectability, Renderability, etc restrictions toggles as needed.

Comment: For illustrations in images, see my answer to the new question Ray Mairlot created from your question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158215/why-doesnt-the-disable-for-viewport-selection-button-doesnt-show-up-in-the-o